# How to change leaflet marker options dynamically?

Tags: leaflet, cartography, markers

I want to change the draggable state of leaflet marker on some event. Now, we use marker.options.draggable to get the draggable state of that marker. However, I want to set/change that draggable state in some event.

```
marker  = L.marker([lat,lng],{draggable:true});
draggable_state = marker.options.draggable;
```

But, below is not working:

```
marker.options.draggable=false;
```

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marker's have a property called `dragging` which is an instance of [Draggable](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable). You can use `marker.dragging.enable()` and `marker.dragging.disable()` to turn dragging on and off. Here's an example:  http://jsbin.com/sowere/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the awesome example. This is what I really wanted. :)